# how to replace values in columns by new values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this code:

```
def chgFormat(x):
    newFormat = 0
    if x[-1] == 'K':
        if len(x)==1:newFormat=1000
        else:newFormat = float(x[:-1])*1000
    elif x[-1] == 'M':
        newFormat = float(x[:-1]) * 100000
    elif x[-1] == 'B':
        newFormat = float(x[:-1]) * 1000000
    elif x[-1] == 'H':
        newFormat = float(x[:-1]) * 100
    elif x[-1] == 'h':
        newFormat = float(x[:-1]) * 100
    else:
        newFormat = float(x)
    return newFormat


frame=pd.read_csv(folderpath+"/StormEvents_details-ftp_v1.0_d1951_c20160223.csv",index_col=None,encoding = "ISO-8859-1",header=0,low_memory=False)
frame['DAMAGE_PROPERTY'].fillna('0K',inplace=True)
frame['DAMAGE_PROPERTY'].apply(chgFormat)
```

This code converts data entries like `2K, 3K, 3H, 3B` into `2000.0, 3000.0, 300.0` etc.

What I want is this code should replace column entries by the values calculated by vales in written function. If I do `print(frame['DAMAGE_PROPERTY'])` after the written code, I still see the original values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this

```
frame['DAMAGE_PROPERTY'] = frame['DAMAGE_PROPERTY'].apply(chgFormat, axis=1)
```